# Angular: how tooltip-trigger works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a tooltip that should be shown on keyup when value of it is invalid. I don't know why

```
<input name="myInput" tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'keyup', false: 'blur'}[true]}}" ...
```

always shows me a tooltip,

```
<input name="myInput" tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'keyup', false: 'blur'}[false]}}" ...
```

never shows me it,
and why

```
<input name="myInput" tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'keyup', false: 'blur'}[myForm.myInput.$invalid]}}" ...
```

also always shows me a tooltip even if `$invalid` is changing.

What could be the reason of third example? How to make it behave as we can expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are binding it once only you need to update `{{{true: 'keyup', false: 'blur'}[myForm.myInput.$invalid]}}` value on change of input field. You can use `ng-change` function for that & then update the tooltip trigger value on change.

**Markup**

```
<input name="myInput" ng-change="updateTooltip()"
tooltip-trigger="{{tooltipTriggerType}}" .../>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.updateTooltip = function(){
    $scope.tooltipTriggerType = {true: 'keyup', false: 'blur'}[$scope.myForm.myInput.$invalid]
    return $scope.tooltipTriggerType;
};
```

Comment: Could you tell me where the difference is? For me it seems to be the same code as in my third example.

Comment: @Cris that was silly one from me..could you look at my update